# Select message implementation based on message type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to build a messaging system that accepts messages in file format using spring integration. Based on the contents of the file, I need to invoke different service activators. I am invoking a header enricher that analyses the contents and sets a message type header. Now based on the message type in the header, I need to route to different service activators. I can do it using a header based router, but the problem is that number of message types is not a finite list. There are a wide variety of messages that I need to process and I don't want to have so many different channels to be created.

Basically I am looking for a solution in which based on the header value, I need to pick different implementation classes at runtime in order to process that message. Is there a better way to do it rather than using a switch statement or if/else statement by leveraging the spring integration framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean, defining a MessageProcessorService:

```
public interface MessageProcessorService {
    void process(Message message);
}
```

and then an interface for your service factory:

```
public interface MessageProcessorServiceFactory {
    MessageProcessorService getMessageProcessorService(String messageType);
}
```

in your configuration class you can create your service factory and implement your different message processor:

```
@Configuration()
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public ServiceLocatorFactoryBean serviceLocatorFactoryBean() {
        ServiceLocatorFactoryBean serviceLocatorFactoryBean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
        serviceLocatorFactoryBean
                .setServiceLocatorInterface(MessageProcessorServiceFactory.class);
        return serviceLocatorFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean("typeB")
    public MessageProcessorService typeBProcessorService() {
        return new MessageProcessorService() {

            @Override
            public void process(Message message) {
                System.out.println("Processing a B type message");
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean("typeA")
    public MessageProcessorService typeAProcessorService() {
        return new MessageProcessorService() {
            @Override
            public void process(Message message) {
                System.out.println("Processing an A type message");
            }
        };

    }

    @Bean
    public SomeService someService(){
        return new SomeService();
    }
}
```

Let be SomeService the service where you receive your Message:

```
@Service
public class SomeService  {

    @Autowired
    private MessageProcessorServiceFactory factory;

    public void doSomething(Message message) {
        String messageType = message.getType();//Type must be typeA or typeB, matching processor beans names

        MessageProcessorService messageProcessorService = factory.getMessageProcessorService(messageType);
        messageProcessorService.process(message);
    }
}
```

So, by using MessageProcessorServiceFactory, you can get a different implementation of a processor for each different message type.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks.. looks very elegant!!